# Resource comparing power consumption of different water heaters?

Tags: water-heater, energy-efficiency

I am looking for a website the compares the "real-world" energy consumption of different electric tankless water heaters under different conditions. Any ideas?

Comment: all electric heat is the same efficiency: ~100%.

Comment: @dandavis, that's true in a technical sense, but misleading when talking about hot water heaters, since as Ecnerwal discusses below, heat pump water heaters can easily beat this if you can steal heat from the environment.

Comment: Why are you focused solely on tankless heaters here?

Comment: I thought it would make things simpler if I went category-by-category. Plus I'm not sure I'm ready to send the extra money for heat pump.

Comment: @capet -- the differences between unit categories vastly dwarf the differences between units within a category

Comment: The real upfront cost of an electric tankless is the high amp requirement that most likely would cost ~$1500+ for new service panel, wiring, etc for 80-120 amp.  In an apartment you would not be allow to do such a major electrical change.  A standard electric WH only requires a 30A/240v circuit which you already have.

Comment: thanks @Programmer66! Am I correct that the heat pump hybrid heaters do not have similar requirements?

Comment: The heat pump electrical requirement is the same as a standard electric WH (30A/240V), just use a lot less electricity and cost less to operate than a gas WH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "real world" energy consumption of any electric tankless (lots of big fat wires and breakers) will almost directly match the amount of hot water you use, at what temperature, and what the water temperature of the supply is - they are nearly 100% "efficient" in that power going in is used almost entirely to heat water going out. Differences between units will be miniscule. Differences between the (US-Market) "Energy Guide" label and YOUR costs will depend on your actual use of hot water, your actual cost of electricity .vs. the amount assumed on that label (which is stated, at least) and your incoming/outgoing water temperatures *.vs.* what they assume. "Your real world cost" for any one of them will be pretty much identical, and may be higher or lower than the Energy Guide number (which is an attempt to come up with a "real world" number for comparison purposes.)

A plain electric resistance tank-type heater will (also) be almost indistinguishable in "real world operating costs" if you use hot water on a more or less daily basis, since modern insulation standards are quite high, and it will do so without requiring the typical 2 or 3 40A breakers to run it that an electric tankless does. "Standby losses" in current market electric tank heaters are very small.

That does not mean *cost efficient* in most markets, where a fuel based heater will usually cost much less to operate, due to comparative fuel/electricity prices, despite various real or perceived inefficiencies. Only where electricity is comparatively inexpensive does it win. Likewise, where your wintertime heat is not electric resistance (and perhaps even where it is given any cooling season to speak of) a tank-type heat pump water heater can be 200-300% efficient (in electric power terms - there is no magic, just borrowing heat from the air, and in wintertime your heat will work a bit harder as a result; but if your heat costs less to run than electric resistance, you'll still save money on heating water.)

Do be sure to insulate all your hot water lines and the cold water lines near the water heater if you are concerned with efficiency and operating costs.

Comment: Thanks! I have also been wondering how best to insulate my water lines, with different levels of effort ranging from "unskilled weekend project" to "pay a contractor up to $1000." If you want, I can give more details about my situation and/or make a dedicated question for this. I live in a second-floor apartment in the US Midwest, with a fair amount of latitude to make modifications to the place.

Comment: So, what are your actual options for heating water? Most of "the midwest" seems to have natural gas widely distributed at very reasonable prices .vs. electricity. In the olde Northeast it's much more "urban only" and electric, oil or propane are the only options if you'e not urban enough for a gas line. Pipe insulation probably deserves its own question, though most of the difference between you and "a pro" is "free labor" and (sometimes) more attention to details where they can't be seen. That depends on how pro the pro is, of course, but that can be hard to know until after the fact.

Comment: Thanks! I believe that my actual realistic options are anything based on electricity only. I do not have a gas line attached and I don't think my landlord would appreciate heat pump stuff. I don't think I can afford solar and I don't want the inconvenience of on-site fuel tanks. I also like the idea of having electrical appliances in case one day my area gets closer to 100% renewable, or I can get me some solar. But I could me missing something....

Comment: @capet, what's your concern with "heat pump stuff"?  The noise?  They look and work exactly the same as any other tanked hot water heater; the only real difference is that they sound like an air conditioner and blow cold air out of them, but otherwise they're exactly like conventional electric ones, only they take less electricity to run.

Comment: Solar panels are a lot more practical for apartment dwellers if you mount them in a different place than your roof. I recommend Antelope Valley, California.

Comment: @Nate S. Thanks! I assumed that heat pump would require drilling holes in the walls, possibly to the outside. I could be wrong about that. Also, I thought that heat pumps were pretty expensive and might not work well in cold climates. Maybe I should give them another look.

Comment: @capet, those kind do exist as well, where part of it goes outside like a split air conditioner, but in my experience that's less common than the all-in-one type.  And yeah, they're not quite as efficient at low temperatures, but worst-case they'll turn on backup heat and be exactly the same efficiency as a traditional electric.  And if you locate it somewhere that doesn't get that cold (i.e. in your house) then it's not a problem.  The only real downside is that they cost a bit more upfront.

Comment: Here's one example of the kind of heat pump water heater I'm talking about: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rheem-Performance-Platinum-50-Gal-10-Year-Hybrid-High-Efficiency-Smart-Tank-Electric-Water-Heater-XE50T10H45U0/312742081

Comment: I have a heat pump water heater that I just installed myself.  It is quiet, less noise than the furnace fan.  No additional holes required.  It only requires a 240/30 amp circuit.  The upfront cost can be significantly higher.  But in @capet, Hot water heater should be a landlord responsibility, so to me, It would be hard to recovered the cost of any water heater just from operating saving.

Comment: @Nate S One other thing I forgot to mention about the heat pump ones: It seems like they often need a lot of overhead clearance. Is that universally true?

Comment: @capet, that's a common design, that many of them exhaust out the top, but it's not universal.  The one I linked only calls for 6" of top clearance in its instructions: https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/3c/3c9717fd-0b98-43d3-ada9-73b6b8928948.pdf

Comment: Oops @Nate S., never thanked you for this! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have qualified your question to just Electric On-Demand water heater.  Most energy efficient is not necessary the same as lowest cost when evaluating different energy source.

I do not believe you will find a source that meets the “"real-world" energy consumption of different electric tankless water heaters under different conditions.  Any ideas?”.

Mainly because it is costing the manufacturers enough just to test under the specific guidelines required by the DOE.  Using the DOE energy consumption guide for all appliances sold in the US will provide you the relative ranking of all the  tankless water heater.  This
[list of electric tankless water heaters](https://www.regulations.doe.gov/certification-data/c/CCMS-4-Water_Heaters.html#fq=%7B!tag%3DType_of_Heater_s%7DType_of_Heater_s%3A%22Instantaneous%20Electric%20Water%20Heater%22&q=Product_Group_s%3A%22Water%20Heaters%22%20) provides a list of 115 models sold or previously sold in the US.
From this listing you can make a list of what features you considered most important, i.e., operating cost, recovery, on-demand rate.

Comment: This is a great answer too, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

When a tankless is operating, essentially 100% of the energy must go into the water.  If even 1% went anywhere else, the unit would self-immolate!  And why would it, when it has flowing water to carry heat away.

So your question *seems* silly.

But it’s not. The gotcha is standby aka vampire load.  The 8 kWh question is, “What is the unit drawing *the rest of the time?*” That standby power is what you need to research.

It is inconsequential compared to active load, but it is on 24x7, so it adds up.

Comment: This is a great answer too. It suggests that standby power consumption might be more important than the marked answer would have led me to believe.